# Howto render dynamically components from another module in Angular

Tags: angular

We use own written angular8 library and include this in our main project.
The library contains the layout and some other stuff we often use.
The layout has on the left side a side menu and at the top a Material Menu.

What we want now is, that in this library we want to extend the menu with items it just knows during runtime. Either per injection or another technique.

Or

Render components from another module which are only available during runtime.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are entryComponents

https://angular.io/guide/entry-components

You can inject them without refering in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can label your target component using id eg. #container like:

then get a reference in code behind like: 
@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef;

then use Angular "ComponentFactoryResolver" to dynamically add menus.